# One query for one join that uses first result in second (subquery) to get all rows

Tags: mysql, join, select, subquery

so I have been struggling with this one for a while. While I could indeed just make two separate queries for this problem, I wonder if it would be possible to do one query. I think a SQL pro will certainly know how to get this done. So here is the thing:

We have two tables posts and post_translations. Abbreviated for simplicity.

```
posts
------
id

post_translations
-----------------
id
post_id (which is the FK on posts...)
locale
slug
content
... (and so on)
```

It's clear for me that I could now do a very simple INNER JOIN to get all posts translated in a specific language, let's say 'en' or 'de' if you want. So I am not gonna bother you further with this.

But as the table will also hold sub locales, such as en (for USA), en-GB, en-AU, de (for Germany), de-AT, de-CH .... the whole thing becomes a bit more complex for following szenario.

Let's say there are posts translated in the languages 'de' only and also in 'de-AT'. The table would then look like:

```
post_translations
id    post_id   locale    content
1        1       de         ...
2        1       de-AT      ...
3        2       de         ...
```

So post 1 is available in 'de' and 'de-AT'. Post 2 is only available in 'de-AT'.

If I want to have all posts in 'de' that's easy. I just add a WHERE locale = 'de' and I am good. But let's say I want all posts in 'de-AT' and all other posts in 'de' that **are not translated** in 'de-AT' so I don't get any duplicates - how can I achieve that in one query? As mentioned earlier, I could run two queries here, first I get all the posts in 'de-AT', then I get all the posts in 'de' and use the 'post_id's I got from the first query with a WHERE not IN query, so I don't get any duplicates.

These queries would be then:

```
SELECT 
    pt.post_id
FROM
    posts AS p
        INNER JOIN
    post_translations AS pt ON p.id = pt.post_id
WHERE
    pt.locale = 'de-AT';
```

and from this query you would use the post_id in this one:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    posts AS p
        INNER JOIN
    post_translations AS pt ON p.id = pt.post_id
WHERE
    pt.locale = 'de' AND pt.post_id NOT IN (*post_ids found in first search*);
```

So staying with the above mentioned post_translations table the desired result would be:

```
p.id     pt.id   pt.post_id pt.locale pt.content
    1      2        1         de-AT      ...
    2      3        2         de         ...
```

p stands for posts and pt for post_translations obviously.

The idea behind the query is to show the specific posts for a region, in this case 'de-AT' but also to show the generic posts that were written for 'de' users.

I hope that makes sense. Would appreciate any help on this. Thank You.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, thanks for the heads up, to comply better with that post I wonder what I should add. The SQL queries that would work if used separately?

Comment: Doesn't that rather undermine the point of providing the link?

Comment: Well, I found them quite basic and I think you are right as maybe some others might find them valuable, I ll just add them. Thank You!

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you need.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `not exists`:

```
select pt.*
from post_translations pt
where 
    locale = 'de-AT'
    or (
        locale = 'de'
        and not exists (
            select 1 
            from post_translations pt1
            where pt1.post_id = pt.post_id and pt1.locale = 'de-AT'
        )
    )
```

Alternatively, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        pt.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by post_id order by (locale = 'de')) rn
    from post_translations pt
    where locale in ('de', 'de-AT')
) pt
where rn = 1
```

You can easily modify the above queries to `join` the `posts` table.

Comment: wow, that was quick, appreciated, I basically wrapped the first query (mysql < 8.0) into a join like this: SELECT * FROM blog.posts AS p INNER JOIN (your query'))) AS a ON p.id = a.post_id. (AS a used just as a name, otherwise I didn't get a result). From what I'd understand, to got the other way around, to join first on posts and postd_translation does not work - or maybe just gets super complicated right?

Answer (score 1):

> show the specific posts for a region, in this case 'de-AT' but also to
> show the generic posts that were written for 'de' users

I believe that a simple `WHERE` clause with the operator `IN` would return your expected results.
Then you can use conditional aggregation to flag the posts that have the sub locale that you want and maybe sort these posts first:

```
SELECT post_id, 
       MAX(locale = 'de-AT') AS flag
FROM post_translations 
WHERE locale IN ('de', 'de-AT')
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY flag DESC
```

You can join the above query to `posts` to get the details of each post:

```
SELECT p.*, t.flag
FROM posts AS p INNER JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, 
           MAX(locale = 'de-AT') AS flag
    FROM post_translations 
    WHERE locale IN ('de', 'de-AT')
    GROUP BY post_id
) t ON t.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY t.flag DESC
```